# Lock or wait cache load

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking

We need to lock a method responsible for loading database date into a HashMap based cache.

A possible situation is that a second thread tries to access the method while the first method is still loading cache.

We consider the second thread's effort in this case to be superfluous. We would therefore like to have that second thread wait until the first thread is finished, and then return (without loading the cache again).

What I have works, but it seems quite inelegant. Are there better solutions?

```
private static final ReentrantLock cacheLock = new ReentrantLock();
private void loadCachemap() {
    if (cacheLock.tryLock()) {
        try {
            this.cachemap = retrieveParamCacheMap();
        } finally {
            cacheLock.unlock();
        }
    } else {
        try {           
            cacheLock.lock(); // wait until thread doing the load is finished
        } finally {
            try {
                cacheLock.unlock();
            } catch (IllegalMonitorStateException e) {
                logger.error("loadCachemap() finally {}",e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your flow will only ensure that `retrieveParamCacheMap()` will *not* be called in this flow i.e, from `loadCachemap()`. Any other thread can call your `retrieveParamCacheMap()` from a different place. Is this what you want?

Comment: retrieveParamCacheMap() is set to private, and any access to it will go through this load method. However, your point is well noted. For more security, it may be necessary to further separate.

Comment: Your solution works only if the second (and any subsequent) thread executes this code while the first one is working on it and holds the lock. But as soon as it has finished and released the lock, the next thread will succeed on `tryLock()` and hence start creating a new map.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer a more resilient approach using read locks AND write locks. Something like:

```
private static final ReadWriteLock cacheLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
private static final Lock cacheReadLock = cacheLock.readLock();
private static final Lock cacheWriteLock = cacheLock.writeLock();

private void loadCache() throws Exception {
    // Expiry.
    while (storeCache.expired(CachePill)) {
        /**
         * Allow only one in - all others will wait for 5 seconds before checking again.
         *
         * Eventually the one that got in will finish loading, refresh the Cache pill and let all the waiting ones out.
         *
         * Also waits until all read locks have been released - not sure if that might cause problems under busy conditions.
         */
        if (cacheWriteLock.tryLock(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
            try {
                // Got a lock! Start the rebuild if still out of date.
                if (storeCache.expired(CachePill)) {
                    rebuildCache();
                }
            } finally {
                cacheWriteLock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the `storeCache.expired(CachePill)` detects a stale cache which may be more than you are wanting but the concept here is the same, establish a write lock before updating the cache which will deny all read attempts until the rebuild is done. Also, manage multiple attempts at write in a loop of some sort or just drop out and let the read lock wait for access.

A read from the cache now looks like this:

```
public Object load(String id) throws Exception {
    Store store = null;
    // Make sure cache is fresh.
    loadCache();
    try {
        // Establish a read lock so we do not attempt a read while teh cache is being updated.
        cacheReadLock.lock();
        store = storeCache.get(storeId);
    } finally {
        // Make sure the lock is cleared.
        cacheReadLock.unlock();
    }
    return store;
}
```

The primary benefit of this form is that read access does not block other read access but everything stops cleanly during a rebuild - even other rebuilds.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to fill a read-only map which is initialized from database once requested, you could use any form of double-check locking which may be implemented in a number of ways. The easiest variant would be the following:

```
  private volatile Map<T, V> cacheMap;

  public void loadCacheMap() {
      if (cacheMap == null) {
          synchronized (this) {
              if (cacheMap == null) {
                  cacheMap = retrieveParamCacheMap();
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

But I would personally prefer to avoid any form of synchronization here and just make sure that the initialization is done before any other thread can access it (for example in a form of init method in a DI container). In this case you would even avoid overhead of volatile.

**EDIT:** The answer works only when initial load is expected. In case of multiple updates, you could try to replace the tryLock by some other form of test and test-and-set, for example using something like this:

```
  private final AtomicReference<CountDownLatch> sync = 
    new AtomicReference<>(new CountDownLatch(0));

  private void loadCacheMap() {
      CountDownLatch oldSync = sync.get();
      if (oldSync.getCount() == 0) { // if nobody updating now
          CountDownLatch newSync = new CountDownLatch(1);
          if (sync.compareAndSet(oldSync, newSync)) {
              cacheMap = retrieveParamCacheMap();
              newSync.countDown();
              return;
          }
      }
      sync.get().await();
  }
```

Comment: This was my starting point. The problem with double checked locking in my case is that I also need to reload the cache at times. That means the null check will only work on application load, but not if reloading because of, for instance, database changes from external origin.

Comment: Double checked locking is an invalid initialization pattern.

Comment: @xTrollxDudex, DCL works fine since Java 5, but it seems won't help in this case.

Comment: @Zaan, you should point that in the description as it was not obvious at least for me

Comment: @AngryJuice Oh please. Even JCIP disapproves the use of DCL, after the release of Java 5.0

Comment: @xTrollxDudex Which does not prevent using it widely for lazy initialization in many places including the Scala lazy values implementation. Anyway, this is off topic here.

Comment: Explain to me how it is offtopic to be pointing out a major flaw in an upvoted answer? Bring this to http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59125/dcl-chat

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say how complicated your structure is and how much concurrency / congestion you need. There are many ways to address your need.

If your data is simple, use a ConcurrentHashMap or similar to hold your data. Then just read and write in threads regardlessly.

Another alternative is to use actor model and put read/write on the same queue.